# Pandas groupby throws an error when using sum()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to calculate the between cluster scatter matrix. In order to do that, for each cluster (named "group" in the example below), I need to perform an operation which results in a matrix and subsequently perform an element-wise addition of the matrices from each cluster.

To do this I try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
                   'A': [1.5, 0.5, 2.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5],
                   'B': [3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5]})
features = list(df.columns)
features.remove('group')


def g(x, mu):
    y = np.array([np.mean(x) - mu])
    print((y.T @ y)*len(x))
    print("")
    return (y.T @ y)*len(x)


m = len(df.index)
mu = df.groupby('group')[features].apply(lambda x: (np.multiply(x.count(), np.mean(x)))/m).sum()
print("mu:")
print(mu)

Sb = df.groupby('group')[features].apply(g, mu=(mu)).sum()
```

This example throws a  `TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type` error on the last line. The print statement in the `g` function shows the result as expected, see below, so I believe the error is due to the `.sum()` operation.

```
[[0.2553 0.1458]
 [0.1458 0.0833]]

[[1.5052 1.0625]
 [1.0625 0.75  ]]

[[0.7912 0.625 ]
 [0.625 0.5    ]]
```

The result I was expecting by adding the `.sum()` operation was the element-wise addition of the three matrices above.

The expected output is:

```
[[2.5416 1.8333]
 [1.8333 1.3333]]
```

Any ideas why this is giving me an error and what I can do to correct it?

**Update 1:**
Using:

```
Sb = df.groupby('group').apply(g, mu=(mu)).sum()
```

instead of

```
Sb = df.groupby('group')[features].apply(g, mu=(mu)).sum()
```

gives the correct matrix, padded with nans. Why does `features` cause an error?

Comment: Minor suggestion `df.columns.tolist()` returns the same output as `list(df.columns)`

Comment: Could you provide your expected output?

Comment: @rpanai expeced output added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
sb=df.groupby('group').apply(g, mu=(mu)).sum()
```

it gives the following result:

```
[[2.54166667 1.83333333        nan]
 [1.83333333 1.33333333        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan]]
```

Is it what you want ?

You still have to deal with the nans though

**Edit to answer your comments:**

To answer you problem in the comments you could change your function as below:

```
def g(x, mu):
    x=x[["A","B"]] #or x=x[features]
    y = np.array([np.mean(x) - mu])
    print((y.T @ y)*(len(x)))
    print("")
    return (y.T @ y)*(len(x))
```

and then:

```
sb=df.groupby(['group']).apply(g, mu=(mu)).sum()
print(sb)
```

which gives:

```
[[2.54166667 1.83333333]
 [1.83333333 1.33333333]]
```

Comment: Thanks! any ideas as to why specifying "features" causes an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to specify feature. Any reason ?

Comment: My thinking was that by specifying features I would be able to remove the "group" column, which specifies the cluster that each record belongs to. This way I would avoid any operations on that column that would affect the results.

Comment: if you do `df[features].groupby(['group']).apply(g, mu=(mu)).sum()` it can not work as you don't have any 'group' feature in your dataframe

Comment: And `df.groupby(['group'])[features].apply(g, mu=(mu)).sum()` cannot work either as after the groupby you get a matrix without column names. I'm going to edit my anwser to share an idea